# ImportError: cannot import name 'prod' from 'math' (unknown location)

Tags: python, math, importerror

When I try to run

either :

```
from math import prod
```

or:

```
import math
arr = (1,2,3)
math.prod(arr)
```

I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'prod' from 'math' (unknown location)
```

or:

```
AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'prod'
```

Meanwhile, there is an article about the usage of this module: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-prod-method/.

(How) Can I use the `prod` module from `math`?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It seems that `prod` is in the `math` module for Python 3 but not for Python 2

Comment: In fact `prod` wasn't introduced until Python 3.8 https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod

Comment: I see, I am using 3.7 indeed